# C# Typecast Generic ref parameter

Tags: c#, generics

How would I get this to work?  Looking to have result updated with the 100 using generic typing.  Any ideas?  Of course this function isn't complete, I just need to get the result functionality working so I can continue.

```
    public static bool ReadMemory<T>(Process process, IntPtr address, ref T result)
    {
        Type objType = result.GetType();

        switch (objType.Name)
        {
            case "Int32":
                result = (T)100;
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How many cases do you have for the switch? Also, I am unable to understand the use of generics when you are checking for type in the code.

Comment: Agree with shahkalpesh. What on earth are you actually trying to acheive here?

Comment: Indeed. You're doing it wrong. The purpose of generics is to be, well, *generic*. If you have to do different things for different type arguments then it's not *generic*.

Answer (score 1):

i would actually refactor this and return the result. i would throw an exception if the switch or if/else locks fell through to the bottom of the method. You could then catch the failure in try/catch in the client code.

Answer (score 0):

you need to just speciailize it for types:

```
public static bool ReadMemory(Process process, IntPtr address, ref int result)
{
   result = 100;
   return true;
}

public static bool ReadMemory(Process process, IntPtr address, ref float result)
{
   result = 100.0f;
   return true;
}
```